# Graph of a 3D discrete-time dynamical system

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, nonlinear, difference-equations

I have a set of difference equations defining a 3D dynamical system with specific parameter values. How can I create a 3D phase portrait to display its trajectories and identify potential attractors?

$x_{n+1}=80-0.5x_n-0.6x_ny_n+x_n,$

$y_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2}{2+x_n^2}z_n-0.2y_n+y_n,$

$z_{n+1}=\left(-0.4+0.008x_n-0.00004x_n^2\right)z_n+z_n$

$(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in A=\{(x,y,z):80\leq x\leq 50(2+\sqrt{10}),0\leq y\leq 5/6,0\leq z\leq 1/6\}$

Comment: You need to specify the parameter values and if possible a sample of your code. Otherwise, it's too difficult to get any help here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Zafar! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to start. Ideally the question should be accompanied by an attempted coding

I assumed the recursive relations have no error and that I made no mistakes in  simplifications.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := {80 + 0.5 x - 0.6  x  y, 
  x^2 z/(2 + x^2) + 0.8  y , (0.6 + 0.008  x - 0.00004 x^2) z}

ir = ImplicitRegion[{80 <= x <= 
     50 (2 + 10 \[Minus] \[Minus]\[Sqrt]10), 0 <= y <= 5/6, 
    0 <= z <= 1/6}, {x, y, z}];
test = RandomPoint[ir, 100];
nf[x_, n_] := NestList[f @@ # &, x, n]
data = nf[#, 3] & /@ test;
```

Visualizing trajectories:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Line /@ data, Point /@ data}, 
  BoxRatios -> {10, 20, 10}], 
 RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/ecoevo).

```
<< EcoEvo`

SetModel[{
  Aux[x] -> {Equation :> g0 - g1 x - c x y + x},
  Aux[y] -> {Equation :> s1 x^2/(s2 + x) z - k y + y},
  Aux[z] -> {Equation :> (-d0 + r1 x - r2 x^2) z + z},
  Parameters :> {g0, g1, c, s1, s2, k, d0, r1, r2},
  ModelType -> "DiscreteTime"
}]
```

Set parameters:

```
g0 = 80; g1 = 0.5; c = 0.6; s1 = 1; s2 = 2; k = 0.2; d0 = 0.4; r1 = 0.008; r2 = 0.00004;
```

Solve for equilibria:

```
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
(* {{x -> 160., y -> 0, z -> 0}, {x -> 100., y -> 0.5, z -> 0.00102}} *)
```

and check their stability by calculating eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix at each equilibrium:

```
EcoEigenvalues[eq]
(* {{0.856, 0.8, 0.5}, {1., 0.669775, 0.330225}} *)
```

The first equilibrium is stable (all eigenvalues less than 1 in magnitude), but linear stability analysis fails on the second one (dominant eigenvalue = 1).  If we run a simulation close to the second equilibrium, we can see that it's unstable but takes a long time to get going.

```
sol = EcoSim[{x -> 99, y -> 0.5, z -> 0.00102}, 10^6];
PlotDynamics[sol, {x}]
```

[image]

So this is an unusual set of parameters that happen to be right on a bifurcation point.  If we change `d0` just a little bit, it behaves better.

```
d0 = 0.399;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
EcoEigenvalues[eq]
(* {{x -> 160., y -> 0, z -> 0}, {x -> 95., y -> 0.570175, z -> 0.00122564},
  {x -> 105., y -> 0.436508, z -> 0.000847281}} *)
(* {{0.857, 0.8, 0.5}, {0.988517, 0.682496, 0.286882}, {1.0102, 0.657438, 0.370456}} *)
```

Now there are two equilibria with `y > 0` where there used to be one.  One is stable and the other unstable.  So I suspect `d0 = 0.4` is a [saddle-node bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle-node_bifurcation).

If we change `d0` more, we can get a nice picture by running a bunch of simulations with initial conditions on a grid:

```
d0 = 0.35;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
EcoEigenvalues[eq]
(* {{x -> 160., y -> 0, z -> 0}, {x -> 64.6447, y -> 1.22922, z -> 0.00392068},
  {x -> 135.355, y -> 0.151728, z -> 0.000227505}} *)
(* {{0.906, 0.8, 0.5}, {0.897102, 0.760706, -0.0953424}, {1.04085, 0.632522, 0.535595}} *)

ics = Flatten[
   Table[{x -> x0, y -> y0, z -> z0}, {x0, 60, 160, 50}, {y0, 0, 1.2, 0.1}, {z0, 0, 0.001, 0.0001}], 2];
sol = EcoSim[ics, 100];
Show[
 PlotTrajectory[sol, PlotStyle -> Evaluate[If[x > 100, Blue, Orange] /. (FinalSlice /@ sol)]],
 RuleListPlot[eq, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Black}]
]
```

[image]

The trajectories are crudely color-coded by which of the stable equilibria they end up at.  In general, three-dimensional stream plots like this are kind of messy but you can see the basins of attraction.

Comment: How can one get access to your program?

Comment: No need to reply because I figured it out.